# replace jetty with glassfish in example code

Tags: spring, rest, glassfish-3, pom.xml

I am extremely very new to rest api. I am trying to build an api using: Jersey, Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Glassfish 3.1.2, and MySQL. I find a tutorial that looks really good: http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/jersey-spring-and-jpa/ . But it's using Jetty instead of Glassfish.

Can someone please look at it, and with code-level details show me how to replace `jetty` with `glassfish`?

You can scroll to the bottom of the article to get the source code under the heading `The Source Code`

Comment: Did you ever tryed to deploy this application on glassfish, or do you just ask and have never tryed it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                <app>/Users/mariedamier/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                <port>8080</port>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```